# Exposing services in RESTful web service

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I am creating a web service and I follow the RESTful way of doing it. So I have resources such as Person, Ticket etc. I have all the normal CRUD operations, some finders and so on. I also want to expose service methods such as `randomTicket()` which is defined in a `RandomTicketGenerator` class. I am unsure if it is bad to expose service methods in a REST API like this? For instance the path above would be `/randomTicket` and only answer on GET requests.

Answer (score 1):

`/ticket/random` is a bit confusing as it could be interpreted as meaning 'give me the ticket with ID=random'

How about returning a single item via: `GET /ticket?random=true`

Or a list of items via: `GET /tickets?random=true&maxItems=1`

Comment: Yeah, this sounds much better.